# Parsing mesh with more than 65k-vertices in Unity at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, runtime, mesh

I'm trying to load OBJ models in runtime using Unity and C#. I'm using Unity's Wiki parser "FastOBJImporter" http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/FastObjImporter for parsing the OBJ files. 
I can't load a mesh with more than 65,534 vertices since it's a Unity limitation ( http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/471639/mesh-with-more-than-65000-vertices.html )

My idea is passing a big mesh path to FastOBJImporter and generate multiple GameObjects with less than 65k vertices in order to load bigger models.

Does anybody know how can I modify FastOBJimporter safely in order to return a list of sub-meshes instead of a big mesh? Any other solutions/ideas are welcomed.

Comment: For being more specific, the implementation I'm doing is to parse one superlist of vertices, one superlist of triangles, etc. Then I'm generating sub-vertex-list A, sub-vertex-list B and so on with less than 64K vertices. Then I would generate sub-triangles-list A from sub-vertex list A, etc... My question is: how should I generate sub-triangles-lists in order to contain only vertex from a single sub-vertex-list? I'm afraid that lots of triangles will be formed by vertex from different sub-vertex-lists and that will be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

[This script](https://github.com/karl-/pb_Stl) does what you want but with STL model files. It imports the model, no matter how large, by splitting the mesh into submeshes each time 65k verts is reached. STL files can be converted to OBJ files so, I imagine, using a simple converter, or altering the script, could do the trick.

Code below (I take no credit for code).

```
#pragma warning disable 0219

using UnityEngine;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Threading;

namespace Parabox.STL
{
    /*Import methods for STL files*/
    public class STL_ImportScript : MonoBehaviour
    {

        const int MAX_FACETS_PER_MESH = 65535 / 3;

        class Facet
        {
            public Vector3 normal;
            public Vector3 a, b, c;

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("{0:F2}: {1:F2}, {2:F2}, {3:F2}", normal, a, b, c);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Import an STL file at path.
         */
        public static Mesh[] Import(string path)
        {
                try
                {
                    return ImportBinary(path);
                }
                catch (System.Exception e)
                {
                    UnityEngine.Debug.LogWarning(string.Format("Failed importing mesh at path {0}.\n{1}", path, e.ToString()));
                    return null;
                }
        }

        private static Mesh[] ImportBinary(string path)
        {
            List<Facet> facets = new List<Facet>();
            byte[] header;
            uint facetCount;

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs, new ASCIIEncoding()))
                {
                    while (br.BaseStream.Position < br.BaseStream.Length)
                    {
                        // read header
                        header = br.ReadBytes(80);
                        facetCount = br.ReadUInt32();

                        for (uint i = 0; i < facetCount; i++)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Facet facet = new Facet();

                                facet.normal.x = br.ReadSingle();
                                facet.normal.y = br.ReadSingle();
                                facet.normal.z = br.ReadSingle();

                                facet.a.x = br.ReadSingle();
                                facet.a.y = br.ReadSingle();
                                facet.a.z = br.ReadSingle();

                                facet.b.x = br.ReadSingle();
                                facet.b.y = br.ReadSingle();
                                facet.b.z = br.ReadSingle();

                                facet.c.x = br.ReadSingle();
                                facet.c.y = br.ReadSingle();
                                facet.c.z = br.ReadSingle();

                                facets.Add(facet);


                                // padding
                                br.ReadUInt16();
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                //Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                                Debug.Log(e.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return CreateMeshWithFacets(facets);
        }

        const int SOLID = 1;
        const int FACET = 2;
        const int OUTER = 3;
        const int VERTEX = 4;
        const int ENDLOOP = 5;
        const int ENDFACET = 6;
        const int ENDSOLID = 7;
        const int EMPTY = 0;

        private static int ReadState(string line)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("solid"))
                return SOLID;
            else if (line.StartsWith("facet"))
                return FACET;
            else if (line.StartsWith("outer"))
                return OUTER;
            else if (line.StartsWith("vertex"))
                return VERTEX;
            else if (line.StartsWith("endloop"))
                return ENDLOOP;
            else if (line.StartsWith("endfacet"))
                return ENDFACET;
            else if (line.StartsWith("endsolid"))
                return ENDSOLID;
            else
                return EMPTY;
        }

        private static Vector3 StringToVec3(string str)
        {
            string[] split = str.Trim().Split(null);
            Vector3 v = new Vector3();

            float.TryParse(split[0], out v.x);
            float.TryParse(split[1], out v.y);
            float.TryParse(split[2], out v.z);

            return v;
        }


        private static Mesh[] CreateMeshWithFacets(IList<Facet> facets)
        {
            int fl = facets.Count, f = 0, mvc = MAX_FACETS_PER_MESH * 3;
            Mesh[] meshes = new Mesh[fl / MAX_FACETS_PER_MESH + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < meshes.Length; i++)
            {
                int len = System.Math.Min(mvc, (fl - f) * 3);
                Vector3[] v = new Vector3[len];
                Vector3[] n = new Vector3[len];
                int[] t = new int[len];

                for (int it = 0; it < len; it += 3)
                {
                    v[it] = facets[f].a;
                    v[it + 1] = facets[f].b;
                    v[it + 2] = facets[f].c;

                    n[it] = facets[f].normal;
                    n[it + 1] = facets[f].normal;
                    n[it + 2] = facets[f].normal;

                    t[it] = it;
                    t[it + 1] = it + 1;
                    t[it + 2] = it + 2;

                    f++;
                }

                meshes[i] = new Mesh();
                meshes[i].vertices = v;
                meshes[i].normals = n;
                meshes[i].triangles = t;

            }

            return meshes;
        }

    }
}
```

Another solution could be to [dynamically combine vertices that share the same space](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/228841/dynamically-combine-verticies-that-share-the-same.html). When you bring in your models at run time you combine vertices that are within a certain threshold of each other to reduce total vertex count below the 65k limit.

Alternatively, use tools, such as [Mesh Simplify](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/43658) to lower the level of detail, allowing you to optimize performance and reduce polygon counts below 65k to import your meshes without surpassing the 65k limit. There are different, and more affordable options, but this seemed to be one of the better ones available.

Answer (score 0):

The current top answer here is nicely detailed, but the whole problem can be solved with 1 line of code:

```
myMeshFilter.mesh = new Mesh() { indexFormat = UnityEngine.Rendering.IndexFormat.UInt32 }; // To support meshes > 65k verts
```

Correctly setting the index format for the mesh will allow for a bigger list of verts.